# Pandas - insert rows based off value

Tags: python, pandas

My original dataframe:

```
    site    code       type   name
0   a       code_foo    s   
1   a       code_foo    t   
2   b       code_foo    s   
3   b       code_foo    t
```

Desired result:

```
    site    code        type    name
0   a       code_foo    s       1
1   a       code_foo    s       2
2   a       code_foo    s       3
3   a       code_foo    s       All
4   a       code_foo    t   
5   b       code_foo    s       1
6   b       code_foo    s       2
7   b       code_foo    s       3
8   b       code_foo    s       All
9   b       code_foo    t
```

I basically would like to modify the dataframe to where: df['type'] == 's', assign df['name'] == 1 and insert three more rows with values 2, 3 and All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first build a type-name df and then join it to the original DF and sort it by site.

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 'all'},
 'type': {0: 's', 1: 's', 2: 's', 3: 's'}})

pd.merge(df[['site','code','type']],df2,on='type',how='outer')
  .sort_values(by=['site','name'])
  .fillna('')
Out[43]: 
  site      code type name
0    a  code_foo    s    1
1    a  code_foo    s    2
2    a  code_foo    s    3
3    a  code_foo    s  all
8    a  code_foo    t     
4    b  code_foo    s    1
5    b  code_foo    s    2
6    b  code_foo    s    3
7    b  code_foo    s  all
9    b  code_foo    t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new rows to your dataframe as duplicates of the `'s'` rows and then populate the `'name'` column with the values you want:

First add 3 duplicate rows for every row who's `type` value is `'s'`.  Then sort by `site` and `type` so that you preserve the original order.

```
df2 = df.append([df[df.type == 's']]*3, ignore_index=True).sort_values(['site', 'type'])
```

Set all values in the `name` column to the empty string (we will overwrite this value for the `'s'` rows in the next step)

```
df2['name'] = ''
```

Create a list where `[1, 2, 3, 'All']` is repeated n times, where n is the number of original `'s'` rows.

```
name_vals = [1, 2, 3, 'All']*len(df.loc[df2.type == 's'])
```

Assign this list as the values in the `name` column for all rows who's type is `'s'`.  Since they are already sorted, this will put the values where you want them.

```
df2.loc[df2.type == 's', 'name'] = name_vals
```

The index will be a little messed up at this point so if you want you can reset it:

```
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

and the new dataframe looks like:

```
  site      code type name
0    a  code_foo    s    1
1    a  code_foo    s    2
2    a  code_foo    s    3
3    a  code_foo    s  All
4    a  code_foo    t     
5    b  code_foo    s    1
6    b  code_foo    s    2
7    b  code_foo    s    3
8    b  code_foo    s  All
9    b  code_foo    t
```